# Using historical data from other external database

Tags: widget, mashup, fiware

I'm creating widgets statistics and I question arises:
you can make a query to an external database? You can only execute javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Widgets run in the browser, so just Browser execution technologies can be used (HTML, CSS, Javascript, SVG, FLASH, DART...)

As far I know you can't access to an external Database directly from a webpage or a widget (unless it exposes an HTTP/WebSocket api), there is no Javascript ODBC. If your database is able to expose a HTTP/REST api (for example vía MongoDB RestAPI) you will be able to query it. In other case you may need to develop a Back End Proxy (HTTP<->ODBC) encapsulating your Data Base accesses.

Another option (not recomended due to security issues) could be to employ some plugin based technologies within your widgets, probably ActiveX, Flash or an Applet will be able to interact with an external DB.